# Hacking on ROS packages that are dependencies of other packages

Tags: debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found some bugs in the gazebo package for Groovy and would like to fix them. Currently, gazebo is installed via the ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo Debian package. My question is, what's the best practice for setting up a development environment to hack on Gazebo?

The problem is that Gazebo is a dependency of dozens (hundreds?) of other ROS packages, so I can't simply uninstall it and compile it from source. Should I use equivs to create a dummy package for Gazebo, and then compile it from source, or is it possible to have side-by-side installations of the source and packaged versions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67017/hacking-on-ros-packages-that-are-dependencies-of-other-packages/) by [danep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2877/danep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you want an [overlay](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Overlays). That will let you keep the original package but use an experimental package as a "shadow package." (Also, [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/47563/how-do-overlays-work/) question discusses overlays.)

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2877/danep/) on 2013-07-11**:
Ahah, so that's what an overlay is. Thanks! Since Gazebo is currently a 'dry' package, I'll follow the instructions for setting up a [rosbuild overlay](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin)